# How to work with Records, Struct and Array in bigquery without flattening them

Tags: sql, arrays, struct, google-bigquery, record

I have a very nested table in Big query. This is just a part of it:

```
[
      {
        "mode": "NULLABLE",
        "name": "id",
        "type": "INTEGER"
      },
    
      {
        "fields": [
          {
            "fields": [
              {
                "mode": "NULLABLE",
                "name": "Type",
                "type": "STRING"
              },
              {
                "mode": "NULLABLE",
                "name": "Term",
                "type": "STRING"
              },
              {
                "fields": [
                  {
                    "mode": "NULLABLE",
                    "name": "TenderID",
                    "type": "STRING"
                  },
                  {
                    "mode": "NULLABLE",
                    "name": "CardType",
                    "type": "STRING"
                ],
                "mode": "REPEATED",
                "name": "EftInfo",
                "type": "RECORD"
              },
            ],
            "mode": "REPEATED",
            "name": "Trx",
            "type": "RECORD"
          }
        ],
        "mode": "NULLABLE",
        "name": "transactions",
        "type": "RECORD"
      }
    ]
```

I want just to cast data inside of each field, but preserve the structure.
What I came with is this, but it flattens my table, or rather RECORDS become nullable instead of repeated and I do not know how do I arrange them back:

```
select 
"id",
ARRAY( SELECT AS STRUCT CAST(Trx.Type AS  INT64) Type,
CAST(Trx.Term AS  INT64) Term,
CAST(Trx.TrxNum AS  INT64) TrxNum,
ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT CAST(EftInfo.TenderID AS INT64 ) TenderID,
CAST(EftInfo.CardType AS INT64 ) CardType
)EftInfo) Trx ) transactions
from 
   dataset.table, UNNEST(transactions.Trx)Trx, UNNEST(Trx.EftInfo) EftInfo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after trying all combinations of the bove I came to the right result, whic I can explyin. Hopefull, this will save time for someone:

```
SELECT id,
---here just (), because this is structure which cannot have multiple values
(SELECT AS STRUCT 
CAST(transactions.Location AS  INT64) Location,
CAST(transactions.StoreID AS  INT64) StoreID,
---Here array, because this structure can have more entries
ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT 
CAST(TenderID AS INT64 ) TenderID,
CAST(CardType AS INT64 ) CardType
FROM UNNEST(Trx.EftInfo) EftInfo)  EftInfo)
FROM UNNEST(transactions.Trx)Trx)Trx
) transactions
from 
   my_ds.my_table
```

In that way one can go as deep as bq allows to build its struct. A good way to control what is happening are json, which one can see after query execution.